# SVG inside absolutely-positioned div does not display

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg, absolute

This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I'm hoping somebody might have a work-around.
I need the inner div to be absolutely positioned (which appears to be causing the problem).

http://jsfiddle.net/UK6Lb/

```
<body>
   <div style="width: 550px; height: 400px; background-color: rgb(0, 142, 0);">
      <div style="position: absolute;">
            <svg>
               <rect width="40" height="40" fill="#666666"></rect>
            </svg>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like setting the svg height and width to 100% fixes the problem.

Comment: but it breaks Firefox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the SVG a width and height.

```
<svg width="40" height="40">
```

or actually any value greater than 40 will do

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
```

Comment: i was hoping for a solution that would not require me to specify the svg width and height.